# PyQt5: stylesheet and inheritance from QWidget

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, qwidget

My code generates a Window containing two QWidgets, a red (`wg1`) and a blue (`wg2`) one. If they become Fields (commented out) which inherits from QWidget, their color disappears.

My question is: Why is it necessary for a `Field` (which inherits from `QWidget`), to have the line

`self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)`

in its `__init__`-method while a QWidget doesn't need this line?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Field(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)# !!!
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f" click makes {self.name} green")
        self.setStyleSheet("background: #00ff00;")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = QWidget()
    grid = QGridLayout()
    root.setLayout(grid)
    root.resize(300,100)

    wg1 = QWidget()
    wg2 = QWidget()
    # wg1 = Field('wg1')
    # wg2 = Field('wg2')

    wg1.setStyleSheet("background: #aa1111;")
    grid.addWidget(wg1, 0, 0)

    wg2.setStyleSheet("background: #1111aa;")
    grid.addWidget(wg2, 0, 2)

    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation resides in the [section related to QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget) of the stylesheet reference:

> If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom QWidget as below:

By default, QWidget does that by default, but QWidget *subclasses* do not, so you either set the flag or you implement the paintEvent.

In any case, consider using [stylesheet selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) and avoid generic/universal syntax as they often result in unexpected behavior for complex child widgets.